# imageresizer URL API Adding Whitespace to a small image

Tags: imageresizer

I am using the imageresizer URL API

I was hoping there would be a URL call to take a 400px x 200px jpg image and create a 1000px x 1000px jpg image that would:

1. center the image in  the 1000px x 1000px block
2. Pad white space 300px to the left and right of the image
3. Pad white space 400PX to the top and bottom of the image
4. Final image would be the original size with lots of white space.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&scale=canvas&mode=pad&w=1000&h=1000` to do this.

You can control centering with `&align=`  The default is `middlecenter`
Other values are `topleft`, `topcenter`, `topright`, `middleleft`, `middlecenter`, `middleright`,
`bottomleft`, `bottomcenter`, and `bottomright`.